# React url changes but component doesn't view/render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render a component (`AllAssignments.jsx`). This component contains a table which populate some data taken from `MongoDB` and will render with the url `http://localhost:4000/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/`

Here's a screenshot for easy understanding.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQoqn.png)

And in the screenshot you will see `Due Date` which are clickable links to the `http://localhost:4000/instructor/:username/assignments/update/:assignmentID`

eg:- `http://localhost:4000/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/5d0c118ab059491b50361489`

when I click on any of the date link it renders another component `EditAssignmentDate.jsx` which allows users to edit the date.

This `EditAssignmentDate.jsx` will be rendered with a url of `http://localhost:4000/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/5d0c118ab059491b50361489`

for easy understanding here are the links again:

**AllAssignments.jsx** -

`http://localhost:4000/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/`

---

**EditAssignmentDate.jsx** - `http://localhost:4000/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/5d0c118ab059491b50361489`

**My problem:** when I click a `Due Date` it renders the relevant component but when I click `navbar item` which is supposed to direct me and renders `AllAssignments.jsx` **only the url changes but component doesn't render. I can still see the `EditAssignmentDate.jsx` component**

If I were to refresh the page it shows the component (`AllAssignments.jsx`).

Here's my `AllAssignment.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import axio from "axios";
import EditAssignmentDate from "./instructor-edit-assignment-date";
import AllAssignmentsSubsidory from "./instructor-all-assignment-subsidory";

const ShowAssignments = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.assignment.assignmentName}</td>
    <td>{props.assignment.assignmentDescription}</td>
    <td>{props.assignment.courseName}</td>
    <td>
      <Link
        to={`/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/${props.assignment._id}`}
      >
        {props.convertedDate}
      </Link>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

export default class AllAssignments extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      assignmentName: "",
      assignmentDescription: "",
      courseName: "",
      assignmentDueDate: "",
      allAssignments: []
    };
  }

  convertDateToString(date) {
    let today = new Date(date);

    let datee =
      parseInt(today.getMonth() + 1) +
      "/" +
      today.getDate() +
      "/" +
      today.getFullYear();

    var dateString = datee; // Oct 23
    return dateString;

    // var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    axio
      .get("http://localhost:4000/courseweb/assignments")
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          allAssignments: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  getRows() {    
    return this.state.allAssignments.map((currentAssignment, id) => {
      return (
        <ShowAssignments
          assignment={currentAssignment}
          key={id}
          convertedDate={this.convertDateToString(
            currentAssignment.assignmentDueDate
          )}
        />
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>

          <Route
            exact
            path={`/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update`}
            render={props => (
              <AllAssignmentsSubsidory
                {...props}
                username={this.props.username}
                getRows={this.getRows()}
              />
            )}
          />

          <Route
            /* path={`/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/:assignmentID`} */
            path='/instructor/IT17157124/assignments/update/:assignmentID'
            component={EditAssignmentDate}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my `EditAssignmentDate.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import axio from "axios";

export default class EditAssignmentDate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      assignmentDueDate: new Date(),
      assignmentObject: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      assignmentDueDate: date
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component did mount");
    axio
      .get(
        "http://localhost:4000/courseweb/assignments/update/" +
          this.props.match.params.assignmentID
      )
      .then(res => {
        let today = new Date(res.data.assignmentDueDate);

        let datee =
          parseInt(today.getMonth() + 1) +
          "/" +
          today.getDate() +
          "/" +
          today.getFullYear();

        var dateString = datee;
        this.setState({
            assignmentDueDate: new Date(dateString)
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Edit Assignment Date {this.props.match.params.assignmentID}</h1>
        <br />
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Due Date:</label>{" "}
            <DatePicker
              className="form-control"
              selected={this.state.assignmentDueDate}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: navbar not in router? move router up in the components tree ... prepare [mcve]

Comment: Navbar is in the router too... everything is under the `Router`

Comment: one, common router ? show structure / component relations

Comment: What happens when you add "exact" to the second route, the one with assignment_id?